# Rails - How to handle the file uploaded by jRecorder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to record audio using jrecorder and upload it to rails server and save it. I am using rails 2.3.4 and webrick.

jRecoder - https://github.com/sythoos/jRecorder

jRecorder's flash uploader sends the file as application/octet-stream.

On the server i do not see this uploaded file in the params or request data.

Would be great to know how to handle these kinds are uploads on Rails side ?

Thanks,
Uday

Comment: You probably need `request.raw_post`. See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791764/how-to-save-a-raw-data-photo-using-paperclip).

Comment: Here are the [relevant actionscript](https://github.com/sythoos/jRecorder/blob/master/flash-fla/Main.as#L196) [lines](https://github.com/sythoos/jRecorder/blob/master/flash-fla/Main.as#L197). Not sure how to process that in Rails though. As I said before, have a look at `request.raw_post.`